# Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": context deadline exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s, cert-manager

**Cluster information:**

Kubernetes version: v1.24.7+k3s1

Installation method: Rancher 2.7

Host OS: RHEL8

**What did I try:**

Redeploy cert-manager with kubectl;

I was trying to debug the issue and found an official cert-manager guide: https://cert-manager.io/v1.2-docs/installation/kubernetes/#verifying-the-installation. Got the same error:

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "test-resources.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
```

**Description:**

I have deployed a K3S cluster using Rancher and on top of it have installed cert-manager v1.11.0 using yaml file. In that file, I have changed "image" values from default ones to my remote repository in artifactory. All pods are running, but when I install a helm chart or deploy something I get this error message:

```
Error: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded )
```

As well, the cert-manager-webhook pod is logging some errors:

```
Trace[1068908304]: [30.003276269s] [30.003276269s] ENDE0314 15:02:02.236947       1 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/cert-manager/secrets?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dcert-manager-webhook-ca&resourceVersion=360915": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: i/o timeout

W0314 15:03:28.953687       1 reflector.go:424] k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/cert-manager/secrets?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dcert-manager-webhook-ca&resourceVersion=360915": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: i/o timeout

I0314 15:03:28.953816       1 trace.go:219] Trace[516939538]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:169 (14-Mar-2023 15:02:58.949) (total time: 30004ms):Trace[516939538]: ---"Objects listed" error:Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/cert-manager/secrets?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dcert-manager-webhook-ca&resourceVersion=360915": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: i/o timeout 30004ms

(15:03:28.953)Trace[516939538]: [30.004226263s] [30.004226263s] ENDE0314 15:03:28.953837       1 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/cert-manager/secrets?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dcert-manager-webhook-ca&resourceVersion=360915": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: i/o timeout

W0314 15:04:44.919380       1 reflector.go:424] k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/cert-manager/secrets?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dcert-manager-webhook-ca&resourceVersion=360915": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: i/o timeout

I0314 15:04:44.919458       1 trace.go:219] Trace[430405071]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:169 (14-Mar-2023 15:04:14.918) (total time: 30000ms):Trace[430405071]: ---"Objects listed" error:Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/cert-manager/secrets?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dcert-manager-webhook-ca&resourceVersion=360915": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: i/o timeout 30000ms (15:04:44.919)Trace[430405071]: [30.000964846s] [30.000964846s] ENDE0314 15:04:44.919472       1 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/cert-manager/secrets?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dcert-manager-webhook-ca&resourceVersion=360915": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

Here are some logs from the pod of actions-runner-controller that I have deployed using helm:

```
Warning  FailedMount  17m                  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[cert], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-v48zj secret tmp cert]: timed out waiting for the condition

Warning  FailedMount  8m32s                kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[cert], unattached volumes=[tmp cert kube-api-access-v48zj secret]: timed out waiting for the condition

Warning  FailedMount  6m18s (x5 over 19m)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[cert], unattached volumes=[secret tmp cert kube-api-access-v48zj]: timed out waiting for the condition

Warning  FailedMount  103s (x2 over 4m1s)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[cert], unattached volumes=[cert kube-api-access-v48zj secret tmp]: timed out waiting for the condition

Warning  FailedMount  86s (x18 over 21m)   kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "cert" : secret "actions-runner-controller-serving-cert" not found
```

I have tested everything in minikube on my local pc and there works fine. However, it’s worth mentioning that the K3S cluster is running in an isolated environment, but probably that shouldn’t be the case.

Thanks in advance,